# Gitignore not ignoring parent directory files XCode

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I have the folowing folder structure in my XCode project:

```
MyProjectName
- .DS_Store
- MyProjectName
- - .gitignore
- - MyProjectName
- - MyProjectName.xcodeproj
- - MyProjectNameTests
- - MyProjectNameUITests
- MyProjectName.workspace
```

And my .gitignore file contains the folowing lines:

```
.DS_Store
SM_Familias.xcworkspace/
```

But my git status command show me these two files:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ../.DS_Store
    ../MyProjectName.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/Rai.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/
```

Is there any way to ignore files in the parent directory of the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to ignore files in the parent directory of the `.gitignore` file?

Place the `.gitignore` in the parent directory.
`.gitignore` can ignore file in inner folders but it cannot ignore files in the parent folder.

---

### ***`.gitignore is collecting information in a commutative way:`***

- ***`System level`*** - (Global) for example if you are a unix user and you wish to ignore all the *.so files for all your projects you will place it in the global file
- ***`Local`*** - Usually will be at a project level applying for all the content of the given project.
- ***`Per folder`*** - specific definitions for the given folder (for example - ignore password file, log file etc or any other resource you wish to ignore)

If you wish to ignore the parent folder place the `.gitignore` in this folder as well.

---

`.gitignore` accumulate the required patterns from the most top folder and down, it cant "look" up and set any patterns pointing to its parent.